# In Pokémon Go, which Pokémon and movesets should I use to beat Blissey in the shortest time possible?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed now that there is a Blissey
stationed at almost every gym that I encounter.
I decided that if I am going to take over a gym,
I want to do it in the shortest time possible.

**Which Pokémon and with which movesets should I use
to beat Blissey in the shortest time possible?**

Comment: Beats the old days of seeing a gym with 10 Blisseys :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a normal-type, fighting-type moves will be [super effective](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/damage-mechanics) against Blissey which means they will do 1.4x damage.  As normal isn't super-effective against any types, your defender's type doesn't matter very much (though having a fighting-type Pokémon will benefit from [20% additional damage due to STAB](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Same-type_attack_bonus#Pok.C3.A9mon_GO)).  Any high-CP Pokémon who can learn fighting-type moves (and has a high attack stat) is a good choice.

The best choices for this would be [Machamp](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/machamp/#Moves) or [Heracross](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/heracross/) with Counter and Close Combat, but [Poliwrath](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/poliwrath/) with Dynamic Punch would also do quite well.  After that, Primeape, Hitmonlee, or Hitmonchan would be your next best bet.  If you don't have any of those at high CP, just go with your hardest-hitting Pokémon with a fighting-type move or a good moveset (assuming that it doesn't use ghost-type moves).

Comment: Ursaring and Donphan both have fighting moves, and can be quite high (2.5k for a level 30). I don't think Hitmon* and Primeape get very high (not that it means they cant beat Blissey, just they generally dont have the HP / def to sustain its damage)